# Bizarre new battery behavior on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, battery-life, calibration

After my old battery puffed up, it was time to buy a new one for my Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) on stock ROM. After I got my new battery, I put it in and turned on the phone as I had some urgent messages to check. I was supposed to charge it to the max but I skipped that part because of urgency.

Well, I noticed that the screen flickered when the battery was 23% and the phone switched off. I decided to charge it to 100%. After I got the green light I turned on the phone and I noticed that the battery jumped down to 88%; indicating that I needed calibration.

I tried the good ol' discharge-recharge to 100% method, but the battery wouldn't go below 23%. I decided to use some app, like [Advanced Battery Calibrator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BoshBashStudios.advancedbatterycalibrator). After following the on-screen instructions, it asks to switch off the phone and let it charge to 100%.

The bizarre part is that as soon as the battery reaches 90% (in switched-off mode). it jumps back down to 20%.

I do not know what is causing this. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be a faulty battery.

Comment: @ToDo Safe to continue using the battery?

Comment: If it's a new battery you could return it for a replacement under warranty I suppose. About your question: if the phone turns off haphazardly it could cause data corruption so even though I don't think I would cause physical damage (unless it heats up and burns) then at worst you'll need to factory reset the phone.